# Is a dummy SSIS task a good idea

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl

I started a new job a few months ago and am noticing some of the older SSIS packages are built with dummy tasks. For example, if there is a Execute SQL Task and it produces a Boolean result, the True result may go to the task that needs something done. However, there is also a dummy task for False that does nothing and is labeled as such.

Here's an example of what I'm seeing.
[image]

Is this a best practice or proper way to code these types of Tasks? The way I code these types of tasks is to only code the needed task and ignore the other. In the case of my image example, I would code the True but not add a task for the False.

Just curious if I'm doing something wrong here.

Comment: I just had to do this today. The reason was to create a precedence constraint so I could apply a formula expression to it. Since you can't just add a precedence constraint without a preceding task... I had to make a dummy. So hopefully it's an acceptable practice!

Comment: I don't know if it's best practice, and best practice here is probably very subjective, but having the dummy task explicitly shows that that path indeed should do nothing instead of it looking like an oversight

Comment: @squillman how then to create a flow using an expression on a precedence constraint without a preceding (dummy) task to create the constraint? There is no option in an Expression Task to control the flow based on the outcome of the expression itself. Only on the constraint. At least, that's what I found in 2 hours of research today.

Comment: @JacobH I'm saying that the dummy task is a good thing here.

Comment: Oh good! I was confused. I thought you were saying the task was an oversight. But seriously if someone has a better way to do this I'm all ears. Using the Expression Task itself doesn't give any options to control the flow other than Success/Fail of the evaluation of the expression. I guess you could output a variable from the "dummy" task and then use the variable in the constraint? Seems like another step that doesn't add anything to the process other than making the "dummy" task do... something. You could make a Script task or something that throws an exception for "false"? Seems hokey

Comment: You can use expressions to defined the `enabled` property. If not enabled it won't run. But I really don't like this as it's not very obvious. But I think i like the approach above even less.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why adding a dummy task that does nothing?

### (1) Informing Developers

If the goal is **Informing developers** that edits the package then you can write an [annotation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/use-annotations-in-packages) beside of the True precedence constraint, and write that if `False result is not considered or does or does nothing`

### (2) For Debugging purposes

If the adding a dummy task is **for debugging purposes**, then it is not a bad idea. Because it will make the package flow more clear for the viewer. But you have to disable this component before deploying the package on the production server.

### (3) To apply an expression

If the goal is to **apply an expression in the precedence constraint** like mentioned in the comments, then the proper way is to use an [Expression Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/control-flow/expression-task) *(in case that it is connected to a dummy task)*

Also based on this [Microsoft article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140153(v=sql.120).aspx):

> A precedence constraint can use an expression to define the constraint between two executables

So if expression are needed, then **write it in the `True` precedence constraint**, or if expression is needed to assign some values to a variable then like i mentioned above use an Expression Task

Comment: "So if expression are needed, then write it in the True precedence constraint"
don't you need to write it in the True constraint AND write its negation in the False constraint if you want to direct output to one of two branches depending on an expression? That's just begging to get out of sync if you change one branch but screw up the other...

Comment: @nemec the False constraint is the error case. Why setting expression for False constraint??

Comment: OP did say that his False task "does nothing", but if I wanted EITHER the True task or the False task to run based on the results of the Test Logic, I would need to write the True expression in the True constraint and write another expression in the False constraint that does the opposite of the True constraint, right? Note that it may be the "error case", but that does not mean the Test Logic actually caused an SSIS task to fail

Comment: @nemec sorry for misunderstanding. This is an old post. You're right the. Mentioned False is not the error output as i said.

Comment: @nemec if you need the False task to run you should write the expression negation. But in case of a dummy task you don't need that since there is no need for a dummy task

Comment: Thanks @Hadi. I agree :) I wish there was an easier way to manage branching in SSIS than writing the negation manually.

Comment: And, if you want truly do nothing - right click component(I always use script task), and disable it.

Answer (score 1):

In one line standard practise is to create the log if something does not go according to desired logic. It should be logged for future debugging.

If you are expecting true as a result of some boolean logic and it turns out to be false then there should be some structure to log it.

Now coming to use of dummy task it is of no harm but instead of that, some task should be used which can create some logs for future reference.